# Find tags that has partial id value using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's a sample of my HTML file:

```
<div id="document_64219">
    <div id="part_12">
    <p class="keywords_HTAG">
        <strong> Key Words : </strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Decentralization</li>
            <li>Planning</li>
        </ol>
    </p>
```

I want to parse every `div` with an `id` starting with "`part_`" and get its `<li>`:

```
myDivs = soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("^brique_"))
myParagraph = myDivs.find_all_next("p", {"class" : "keywords_HTAG"})

for div in myDivs :
   for paragraph in myParagraph :
        li = paragraph.find_all_next("li")
        print (li)
```

This doesn't return anything to me. I'm used to Jsoup, which I find intuitive enough, but I'm not sure how it's done with Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `*` in css selectors that matches part of value in certain attribute .

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="document_64219">
    <div id="part_12">
    <p class="keywords_HTAG">
        <strong> Key Words : </strong>
        <ol>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>second</li>
        </ol>
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
    </ol>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# if you want the li with in the div with the id contains part_
# This will return first , second , third and fourth 
lis = [li.text for li in soup.select('div[id*="part_"] li')]
print('All li ==>',lis)


# if you want olny the li with in the div with the id contains part_ and with in the p tag only 
# This will return first , second
lis = [li.text for li in soup.select('div[id*="part_"] p.keywords_HTAG li')]
print('with in p only ==>',lis)


# if you want olny the li with in the div with the id contains part_ and without the li in the p tag  
# This will return third and fourth 
lis = [li.text for li in soup.select('div[id*="part_"] > ol  li')]
print('without li in p ==>',lis)
```

Output :

```
All li ==> ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
with in p only ==> ['first', 'second']
without li in p ==> ['third', 'fourth']
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed, thank you for your time.I'm facing another dilemma .  In case I have multiple <ol> <li> in my div and I'm only looking for those in the particular tag <p class="keywords">. is there a way to retrieve those ? I used the following code :

 myDivs = soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("^part_"))
myParagraph = myDivs.findAll("p", {"class" : "keywords"})

for div in myDivs :
   for paragraph in myParagraph :
   #     li = [paragraph.text for p in paragraph.find_all_next("li")] 
        li = paragraph.find_all_next("li")
        print (li)

Comment: yeah seeing all the errors I figured that much.. I'm sorry for that. I just edited the code on my post I hope it helps

Comment: @user93804 Edited the answer to include the case you are trying to solve . If the answer helped you vote it up and accept it to close the post .

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="document_64219">
    <div id="part_12">
    <p class="keywords_HTAG">
        <strong> Key Words : </strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Decentralization</li>
            <li>Planning</li>
        </ol>
    </p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


for item in soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("^part_")):
    print(item.find_all_next("li"))
```

Output:

```
[<li>Decentralization</li>, <li>Planning</li>]
```

Or

```py
for item in soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("^part_")):
    print([item.text for item in item.find_all_next("li")])
```

Output:

```
['Decentralization', 'Planning']
```

Comment: @ahmed Hello, it's pretty much what I need so thank you very much for your time. In case I have multiple <ol> <li> in my div and I'm only looking for those in the particular tag <p class="keywords_HTAG">. is there a way to retrieve those ?

Comment: @user93804 you can apply the same method.